# Java: JButtons not working with action Listener

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JustinSodaMachine extends JApplet
{
   private JButton coke;
   private JButton dietCoke;
   private JButton mellowYellow;
   private JButton water;
   private JButton cherryCoke;
   private Panel aPanel;
   private Panel bPanel;
   private Panel cPanel;
   private int cokeNum = 0;
   private int dietCokeNum = 0;
   private int mellowYellowNum = 0;
   private int waterNum = 0;
   private int cherryCokeNum = 0;
   private double amount;
   private double change;


   private JTextField amountIn;

   public void init()
   {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      buildAPanel();
      buildBPanel();
      buildCPanel();
      add(aPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(bPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(cPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);


         }

   private void buildAPanel()
   {

      aPanel = new Panel();
      Button coke = new Button("Coke");
      Button dietCoke = new Button("Diet Coke");
      Button mellowYellow = new Button("Mellow Yellow");
      Button water = new Button("Water");
      Button cherryCoke = new Button("Cherry Coke");
      aPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1, 10, 40));

      coke.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
      dietCoke.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
      mellowYellow.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
      water.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
      cherryCoke.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());

      aPanel.add(coke);
      aPanel.add(dietCoke);
      aPanel.add(mellowYellow);
      aPanel.add(water);
      aPanel.add(cherryCoke);
      setVisible(true);

   }


   private void buildBPanel()
   {
      bPanel = new Panel();
      JLabel title = new JLabel("Justin's Soda Machine Drinks 0.75 Cent");
      bPanel.add(title);
      setVisible(true);
   }

   private void buildCPanel()
   {
      cPanel = new Panel();
      JLabel amountText = new JLabel("Amount deposited: ");
      amountIn = new JTextField(10);
      amountIn.setText("0");
      amountIn.setEditable(true);


      cPanel.add(amountText);
      cPanel.add(amountIn);
      setVisible(true);
    }



private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {


         double balance = Double.parseDouble(amountIn.getText());

         if(balance < 0.75)
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inadequate amount of money ");

         else
         {

            if(e.getSource() == coke )
            {
               cokeNum++;
               if(cokeNum <= 20)
               {
                  balance = (amount - 0.75);
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The balance is : " + balance + " You selected Cola");
               }
               else
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Out of range ");
            }

            if(e.getSource() == dietCoke)
            {
               dietCokeNum++;
               if(dietCokeNum <= 20)
               {
                  balance = (amount - 0.75);
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The balance is : " + balance + " You selected Lemon-line soda" );
               }
               else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Out of range ");
            }

            if(e.getSource() == mellowYellow )
            {
               mellowYellowNum++;
               if(mellowYellowNum <= 20)
               {
                  balance = (amount - 0.75);
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The balance is : " + balance + " You selected Grape soda" );
               }
               else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Out of range ");
            }

            if(e.getSource() == water )
            {
               waterNum++;
               if(waterNum <= 20)
               {
                  balance = (amount - 0.75);
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The balance is : " + balance + " You selected Dirnk Root beer");
               }
               else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Out of range ");
            }


            if(e.getSource() == cherryCoke )
            {
               cherryCokeNum++;
               if(cherryCokeNum <= 20)
               {
                  balance = (amount - 0.75);
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The balance is : " + balance + " You selected bottle of water");
               }
               else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Out of range ");
            }
            amountIn.setText(""+balance);
         }

      }
   }
}
```

I have tried everything I can think of to make the buttons work for this vending machine to recognize the drink selection and subtract 0.75 cents from the total deposited. I have no clue why this is not working and any help is appreciated. It complies fine in jgrasp with no errors or exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two coke Buttons (`private JButton coke;` as a class variable and `Button coke = new Button("Coke");` as a local variable inside buildAPanel().

From a quick scan, it looks like you are calling `coke.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());` which adds the listener to the **local** (not class) variable. This is also the button you are adding to your panel. This will be important in a second.

Inside your actionPerformed(...) you are looking at the **class** JButton named coke; not the one added to the panel - `if(e.getSource() == coke )`

Remove the Buttons inside buildAPanel() and that should get you moving.

Comment: I can not give you an upvote yet, but it is now working. Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, the op is mixing heavy and light weight compnents, which is going to generate painting issues